# Why do I obtain different sizes in a string buffer?

Tags: c, string, malloc, buffer

Why when I execute this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){
    size_t size = 4;
    char *str = malloc(size);
    str = "hello";
    printf("malloc %s: %d\n", str, size);
    printf("strlen %s: %d\n", str, strlen(str));
    printf("sizeof %s: %d\n", str, sizeof("hello"));
    return 0;
}
```

I obtain the following:

```
malloc hello: 4
strlen hello: 5
sizeof hello: 6
```

Basicly, I just need to know why if I allocate only 4 bytes, I can store a string with 5 chars of a size of 6 bytes?

Comment: And `const char *ptr = "foooooothisistoolong"; sizeof(ptr);` will print the size of a pointer anyway and **not** the length of the string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Q1. **Why do I obtain different sizes in a string buffer?**

Three outputs:

1. `size_t` is four byte in your system. This is the reason `sizeof(size)` is 4, but its **not** because  assignment `size = 4`. Of-course you have printf size value that is also 4.
2. Second, `strlen(str)` gives you the length of string `"hello"`, that is consist of 5 chars. (string length don't include `\0` nul char).
3. A string in C is of `char[N]` (array) type. In 3rd pritnf `sizeof("hello")` value is  `6` because `"hello"` string is 6 chars long array (included strings termination `\0` nul, type of hello is `char[6]`).

   In memory `"hello"` string is stored something like below in diagram:

   ```
    str          23   24   25   26   27   28
   +----+      +----+----+----+----+----+----+
   | 23 |      | h  | e  |  l | l  | o  | \0 |    
   +----+      +----+----+----+----+----+----+

   Address of hello string is first address = 23  
   str: is pointer, used to store address of hello string
   ```

   Assignment `str = "hello";`, basically stores address of string hello to pointer variable `str` as I shown above in figure.

> Q2.   **Why if I allocate only 4 bytes, I can store a string with 5 chars of a size of 6 bytes**

Wrong, actually you are not coping "hello" string into dynamically allocated space. Initially  `str` was contained address returned by `malloc()`. But  due to assignment statement `str = "hello";`, you have overwritten the memory address of allocated memory by constant string literal "hello" in assignment statement.

To understand this, you can execute a example:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){
 size_t size = 6;
 char *str = malloc(size);
 printf("\n malloc str: %p", str);
 str = "hello"; 
 printf("\n hello str: %p", str);
 return 1;
}
```

Output:

```
 malloc str: 0x804a078
 hello str: 0x8048609  // allocated address lost
```

[Codepade link](http://codepad.org/i8FxZFYU)
(Side note: *you should never loss address of dynamically(explicitly) allocated memory, because you need it when you explicitly deallocates it using free().*)

If you wants to copy into allocated space, you can an either (1) assign by accessing/indexing each memory location, or (2) by using library function `strcpy()`.

for example try:

```
       str[0] = 'a';
       str[1] = 'b';
       str[2] = 'c';
       str[3] = '\0';  // nul termination is important 
    or 
       strcpy(str, "abc");  // strcpy add nul itself
```

But you can't copy `"hello"` string because `str` dose not allocated enough space to hold complete string, doing this causes [buffer-overrun](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffer_overflow) problem that is [Undefined behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) in C/C++  at runtime .

Answer (score 1):

With your line `str = "hello"`, you are reassigning your pointer to point to a spot in memory where `"hello"` is created. What you're doing here is having a small memory leak with your `malloc`, since you no longer have a reference to the requested heap space.

Answer (score 0):

`str = "hello"` simply reassigns the pointer; it doesn't store anything in the memory you just allocated.  You've just created a memory leak!

To copy the string content itself, you should use [`strncpy()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strncpy).

Comment: and `str[len - 1] = 0;`, in case `strncpy()` doesn't NUL-terminate the buffer.

Comment: No, don't use `strncpy()`. Read [No, strncpy() is not a "safer" strcpy()](http://the-flat-trantor-society.blogspot.com/2012/03/no-strncpy-is-not-safer-strcpy.html)

Answer (score 0):

This line `str = "hello";` sets the pointer to point to a different location. (If you try doing `sizeof(str)` you will end up with value `4` this being the size of a pointer.)

`strlen(str)` produces the string length without the null character, that is why you have `5`.

`sizeof("hello")` calculates the memory needed to store `"hello"` so it takes in consideration the null character too, that is why the output is `6`. So basicly your string has 6 chars.